# Using the shell method, calculate the value of the solid formed by$ y=(x+12)^ {1/2}$, $y=x$, and $y=0$ rotated about the$ x$-axis.

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

So I am trying to figure out this question as I can't figure out how to get $h(y)$ for this question. I can find the answer online but I am having difficulty understanding why it is the answer which is $h(y) = (y+12-y^2).$ Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a picture, something like.[image: curves] Then you can see that the cylindrical shells of radius $y$ start from the curve $y=\sqrt{x+12}$ and end up at the curve $y=x$. But the cylinder axis is along $x$ direction, so you need to extract $x$ from the above equations. So, to get the lower limit $$y^2=x+12$$ or $$x=y^2-12$$The upper limit is at $$x=y$$
The difference is the height of the cylinder: $$h(y)=y-(y^2-12)=y+12-y^2$$

Comment: Just so that I can understand it a little bit better, why is y^2=x+12 the lower limit when it is above the line y=x? I apologize as this is a hard unit for me to understand and I want to fully understand it. Thank you.

Comment: In the figure above, the cylinder axis is along $x$. Draw a horizontal line, at some $y$ value between $0$ and $4$. Then the $x$ corresponding to the straight line is higher than the $x$ corresponding to the curved line.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. This helps a tremendous amount.